# Using bootstrap to create grid with "dynamic" image sizing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Still brand new to CSS, so please be gentle ;). I have a grid setup like the following:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
       <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-responsive">
       </a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I actually fill the src with an image, I want the image to actually compeltely "fill" the placeholder no matter what the image size is. I guess in other words, a ratio should be applied so it fills the 150x150? The width (max-width: 100%) is fitting, but the height is auto. I've tried adjusting height, width, max-height, etc. with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding height and width attributes within the image tag like so:

`<img src="..." height="150" width="150">`

Not sure how this'll interact with bootstrap's responsive image class. Best practice would be to actually insert an image which has the correct dimensions.

Comment: I'm using django. I guess I COULD force the size to fill the exact dimensions adjusting the size before it goes into the database, but would rather have the ratios change so the images in the database remain unchanged.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to what you are actually trying to achieve. If your image is large enough it should scale down to fit within the column. I'm guessing you're images are too small though, so you'd need to first force a width and height, then (I'm guessing) they will scale down to fit within the column.

Comment: Sorry, was a bit unclear there. I meant to add that I'm using the admin page within django to add the images to a directory, not to a database. The user of the website will be adding images so I don't want him to have to mess with any of the images properties. And sense I'm using img-responsive from bootstrap, it looks like i'm going to have to create custom css as Danny Swan suggested.

Comment: ie if you hard code the width and height, they won't be responsive any more.

Comment: @user3327134 Actually I think if you specify width and height the responsive class overrides that. Could be wrong though.

Comment: Oh yes, you are correct. And that leads us back to the problem lol

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to bootstrap. I must have been messing with this longer than I should have but basically here is what I found works

You want to have a custom stylesheet that you load after bootstrap's css so you can make custom adjustments without destroying the original css. You can then make the adjustments:

```
.thumbnail-image {
overflow: hidden;
height: 150px; 
}

.thumbnail-image > img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

So then I sandwiched the image inbetween a div with the "thumbnail-image" class in the HTML.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
       <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
       <div class="thumbnail-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div> 
       </a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
       <div class="thumbnail-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div> 
       </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

As column sizes adjust at the breakpoints you would have to do some similar adjustments regarding the custom height property of the custom .thumbnail-image class but other than that this is what I came up with!

Comment: This almost gets me there, Danny. It stretched it vertically though. Now it's too tall. It may have to do with my entire setup. I think it's going to take a lot of time to get it right... I'd upvote you, but still too new to community.

Comment: Wow! Check out google's homepage right now with the thumbnails. Exactly what I'm going for.

Comment: Actually, that's not exactly what I was going for. The number of thumbnails "drop off" as the browser gets smaller. I did solve this, however, by using python (since I'm using django).